# VC++ 2010 Member variable and stale .Dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

I am using Microsoft VC++ 2010 and I am wondering how it or in general C++ compilers, figure out how it links .Dlls together.

This came up out of the following use case:
I have been working on a project (call it A) that will produce a .DLL, and this .DLL will be used in another project (call it B), which produces an .exe. I add a new member variable to a class in project A, do some stuff with it and compile it.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> m_new_var;
```

I then work on project B and use the new member variable m_new_var in project A. It compiles fine. When I execute project B in the debugger, I find that whenever the code does anything with the m_new_var in A, it leads to an invalid memory access. After messing around, I found that it would work when I either:

1) Add another member variable of the exact same type such as:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> m_new_var;
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> m_new_var2;
```

2) Deleting my x64 folder and rebuilding everything again.

Obviously solution 1 was not ideal but I don't quite understand why deleting my x64 folder would fix things. I believe this has to do with linking with an old version of the .Dll but I am not sure.

Comment: Not rebuilding projects when such a shared declaration changes is certainly a recipe for disaster.  Protect yourself from mishaps like this by adding your projects to a single solution so they get both rebuilt.  And do avoid sharing global variables across module boundaries, globals are troublesome enough as is.